# ScrapinghubClient > Download CSV

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapinghub

I have a question about using ScrapingHub via ScrapinghubClient.
Is there any way to downlaod a csv file from all completed jobs and then delete them directly from python?
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does https://python-scrapinghub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/overview.html# provide the example you need to get started?

Comment: I searched thoroughly for the choice of receiving a .csv file, but I couldn't find anything!
I am sure there has to be a way to do that.
Every help would be appreciated